# Limit an input to a range Python

Tags: python

I get some user input and if they pick a value outside of a given interval I want to set the value to the edge value. I can do it like this:

```
if input > upper_limit:
    input = upper_limit
elif input < lower_limit:
    input = lower_limit
```

It feels like there should be a nicer way of doing this but I can't figure out how. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the min and max functions:

```
input = min(input, upper_limit)
input = max(input, lower_limit)
```

or just

```
input = max(min(input, upper_limit), lower_limit)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the functional way:

```py
i = upper_limit if  i > upper_limit else lower_limit if i <lower_limit else i
```

btw, better to not name your vars as `input`, because you are shadowing a built-in function.